# How do I format my Table of Contents in LaTeX to this?

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, tocloft, titletoc

How do I implement this TOC in LaTeX? This is the TOC of "The Variational Principles of Mechanics" by Cornelius Lanczos.

[image]

Comment: Please provide an MWE showing what you have tried (from `documentclass.... to \end{document}`) in particular what you have in the body of the document. Are there `\part` or `\chapter`, how do you use  `\section`? These are what feed into the ToC.

Comment: I have used only \chapter  and \section (no \part), and the default \tableofcontents with document class memoir

Comment: You still have not provided an MWE. Does your **II. THE CALCULUS OF VARIATIONS** come from a `\chapter` title? If so how have you changed the `\chapter` definition? How does a `\section` appear in the document? Without more from you, goodbye. --- GOM